Given a natural number $n$, is it always possible to find a prime number greater than $\frac{n}{2}$ but less than $n$?
Is the following statement true? If yes, prove it, else give a counterexample.
Given a natural number $n$, is it always possible to find a prime number greater than $\frac{n}{2}$ but less than $n$?
My try:
I tried to prove by contradiction. Suppose there exists a natural number $n$ such that it is not possible to find a prime number greater than $\frac{n}{2}$ but less than $n$.
But I fail to move further from here.
Though I checked with all possible examples, I find the statement to be true. But I cant prove it  mathematically. Can someone please help.
EDIT: Using the fact that there are infinitely many primes, we can guarantee that it is possible to find a prime number greater than $\frac{n}{2}$ but how to show that it will be less than $n$?

You will always find such a prime. Euclid showed that there are infinitly many prime numbers. The proof is elementary. If you would happen to find such a $n$, then you would find a bound for the prime numbers, which can not exist.

Do you mean "greater than $\frac n2$ but less than $n$"?  If so, see Bertrand's Postulate.

@lulu Yes Sir, I meant that

@Cornman, but how do you prove that that it is less than $n$

@Olivia My comment addressed the original question. Not why you always find a prime between $n/2$ and $n$. That is, as pointed out the content of Bertrand's Postulate.

@Cornman; According to Bertrand's Postulate, there exists a prime number between $n$ and $2n$. But how can I find a prime number between $\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$?

@Lulu;According to Bertrand's Postulate, there exists a prime number between  and 2. But how can I find a prime number between $\frac{n}{2}$ and ?

@Olivia This is just the same. If you set $m=n/2$ (maybe after rounding to a natural number)  and $n=2m$.

Some trivial counterexamples: $n=1$ and $n=2$.

@Cornman; Thank you so much
